# Issue with access camera after denied the camera

Tags: ios, swift, camera, native

In my application I used camera implementation in that if the user enter very first means that time they choose allow means they have to access camera and photo library in entire application, if it is chosen denied means the user cannot access the camera so that time we need to change camera and photo library in settings.After that we have to access the camera in my case it is not working properly, anyone helps me, much appreciated.

Comment: ask for permision again

Comment: I tried but i unable to access camera and photo library,can you please provide  a some piece of code.

Comment: @PatelJigar I thought it was not possible to ask twice or more for permission when the user did not allowed it the first time

Answer (score 5):

You can check first whether camera permission is allowed or not. If not then you can navigate to settings screen & ask user for permission.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkCameraPermission()
    }
    func checkCameraPermission()  {
        let cameraMediaType = AVMediaTypeVideo
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: cameraMediaType) { granted in
            if granted {
                //Do operation
                print("Granted access for camera")
                self.setCamera()
            } else {
                self.noCameraFound()
                print("Denied access for camera ")
            }
        }
    }
    func noCameraFound(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "AppName", message: "Please allow camera access in phone settings", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Back", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) in


        }));

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open setting ", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) in
            UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

        }));
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you jack,really appreciated,lets check.